# Number as a variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, javascript-framework

```
01. (function(){
02. function b(e){if(!d[e]){var f=d[e]={exports:{}};c[e].call(f.exports,a,f,b)}
03. return d[e].exports
04. }
05. var a=this,c=b.modules=[],d=b.cache=[];
06. c[0]=function(a,b,c)
07. {
08. var d=this;
09. 1;
10. var e=c(1),g=c(3).Builder,h=c(11);var i=c(10);
11. var j=c(15).Circle;var k = c(17).Friend; 
12. l=c(18).SearchFriends;c(19);
```

This is an fb app code that i have copied from fb friend circles,
i am working in a different manner but was going through this script,where

FUNCTION c[0] has a variable 1 in it ...

---

**How can bare numbers be used as variable names in javascript .. ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: `c()` is a function on lines 10-12, passed in on line 6 (third parameter), the number is just a parameter to that function.

Comment: @Dan D. dude that is an expression or a type it is not a duplicate of any other topic.. such a question has never been asked ..!!

Answer (score 2):

That's not a variable, that's an expression.

Comment: please elaborate.. how this expression evaluates ..?does that expression mean function c[0] returns true always ..?

Comment: `1` *is* an expression. so is `1+3`. a couple of languages allow using expressions without actually using them (without assigning them to something or using them as a call parameter to a function, etc...). It's a no-operation

Answer (score 2):

Javascript variable names must begin with a letter or underscore or $.  They may contain numbers, but not start with a number.

The statement you asked about:

```
1;
```

is a no-op.  It's an expression that evaluates to a value of one, but since it isn't assigned to anything, it doesn't do anything.  It doesn't declare a variable.  Chances are it's a typo of some kind in the source you started with.

Comment: Variable names may also begin with `$`.

Comment: {view:"DetailCard",id:"card",pos:"w:88px h:95px",visible:!1} the expression has also been used inside the json array, may be its a boolean but it does appear like an expression

Comment: @Nina.  What is your question about that code?  That is an object declaration that has attributes o.view, o.id, o.pos and o.visible.

Comment: i posted {//json content goes here}  because the strange expression or variable is possibly also used inside the json, may be i am wrong

Answer (score -1):

They are not numbers, they are function calls.
For example, if you have

```
function c(num){
  if(num == 10) return "Edgar";
}
```

when you do:

```
c(10)
```

You get "Edgar" (the function evaluation).
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: :) i asked about the variable/expression/typo inside the function c[0]